# Splitting an array into another array?

Tags: c#

I've tried googling this and looking at questions/answers on here but I'm not having much luck.

I have a list of values that I've already put into an array by splitting on the commas (","), but now I need to split on the colons (":"). I am at a loss for how to do this, everything I've tried so far hasn't working and I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
string AdditionalData = "Name: John, Age: 43, Location: California";
string[] firstData = AdditionalData.Split(',');
```

The above code is how far I've gotten - this works - but no matter what I try I can't figure out how to split the data on the colon. Basically, I'm looking to take the array "firstData" and make that into a new array.

Any help would be appreciated and apologies for the simplicity of the question, I'm new to this!

*Side note: This is part of an asp.net mvc project if that is of any help, the tag was removed. the results are also displayed as a web page, not in the console.*

Comment: You need to tell us what you expect the end data structure to be. It could be as simple as: `AdditionalData.Split(new[] { ',', ':' });`

Comment: So the desired result is a `string[][]`?

Comment: What do you actually want as an end result? i.e what are you trying to do with the data?

Comment: @SteveJ In the end I want to be able to take the values from the second split, i.e, "John","43","California" and assign them to a model that already exists. This preexisting model will then be displayed as part of another, larger model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate each array item using a foreach loop.

```
foreach(string dataString in firstData)
{
  string[] temp = dataString.Split(':')
  //do something with the new array here
}
```

Comment: This worked beautifully and was by far the easiest for me to understand, thank you!

Comment: @Chilly Make sure Accept the answer that works for you. It helps people that find this question in the future and you get rep for it!

Comment: @itsme86 yes I will do, I'm just in the habit of leaving things open for a day or so to allow people to answer, sometimes they don't when they see an accepted answer when it could be very useful :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want, but I'm not sure.

```
var secondData = firstData.Select(str => str.Split(':'));
```